# Is this effect possible in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am using `ViewPager` in `Activity`. I need to have this effect between pages flipping.

[image: This effect]

I have never seen such kind of effect other than in the flipping between home screens of Android. If you have used this animation or if you have heard the name of animation please help me. I don't have any ideas about this animation.

Comment: Cover flow it seems, not exact link but for idea [see here](http://androidsnips.blogspot.in/2011/03/images-with-coverflow-like-animation-in.html)

Comment: @Abhi: never heard of this thing. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I hope Coverflow will leads your need...http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Comment: This works great with images, but a different solution is needed for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is called cover flow. In [this link](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) you can find the code for making a cover flow effect.

You also have another animation effect in Android which is called page curl. Check it out if you are interested in another animation style.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a custom view that extends `SmoothPagedView` -> `PagedView` -> `ViewGroup`. A good place to look is at the Android launcher source. It's actually quite complicated, but [`com.android.launcher2.Workspace` [link]](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/launcher2/Workspace.java?av=f) in Android 4.1.1 should give you an idea of what is done.

It seems the 3D-looking outline you see is created by `HolographicOutlineHelper`, and there are 3D effects applied to the individual `CellLayout`s (or pages).