# ViewPager page effect

Tags: android, android-viewpager, transition, albumart

I need to make a view pager for a music app with [this effect](https://lh4.ggpht.com/G5EZwbVVbgpaSRc4XkZ0CX-lk6BkarZ2AqorQkNfL_b7zGl5HC48OjT5ZK-pnCzdjPE)
I am new to android developing. I got a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257067/is-this-effect-possible-in-viewpager) from stack, but its not helping fully.

Requirement : for a music app, i need to show a the album arts in a view pager. album art of current song at middle along with partially visible album arts of previous and next song on left/right side respectively at the same time.

Comment: This pic has no animation i guess, its just simple pager with side pages visible, right?

Comment: am new to android, could you please help, how can i show the side pages visible.. also i want know , how to make a gallery or cover flow efect in View pager of album art... thanks...

Comment: The links that you provided have completely different effects. Please describe what you actually have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a negative page margin to make the side pages visible. Rest all properties are inherent in ViewPager. Just have a look at the implementation. [Android ViewPager with previous and next pages visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725045/android-viewpager-with-previous-and-next-pages-visible)

**EDIT:** With this you can achieve what you have mentioned. I don't know whats the problem? Default ViewPager has series of pages and with this above mentioned link you can see other pages too. Don't get confused by the pic on top of the link, the result will look more like your link though.

Comment: hi Shakti Thakran, could you please tell me, how can i apply a gallery or Coverflow appearance to viewpager album art... ie the current image at centre and the side images are litle bented towards centre...

Comment: That will take a lot of effort on your part. Here is something to start with http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html